# Navigation Bar flexbox gaps on the sides

Tags: html, css, flexbox, navbar

So, I'm having an issue with the margins on the sides of my navigation bar as there is a little gap that I don't want. To solve this I would make the margin equal to zero for all my elements by using the "*" in my CSS but I don't want my other elements to be affected.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS Grid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body style="background-color: #e3e3e3;">

    <main>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#Owners">Owners</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Properties">Properties</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Property-Managers">Property-Managers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Tenants">Tenants</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Maintanence">Maintanence</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  padding-top: 350px;
}

nav ul {
  background-color: #181919;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  justify-content: center;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

Is there an alternate way for the margins for the navbar to be equal to 0 without affecting my other elements? I would greatly appreciate a solution for this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use
body{

margin:0;
}

to get rid of extra space on the sides of your nav.

Answer (score 0):

The `margin` you're seeing is coming from the built-in browser styles on `body`. Remove the margin and your gap is gone.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;  
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;  
}

nav {
  padding-top: 350px;
}

nav ul {
  background-color: #181919;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  justify-content: center;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#Owners">Owners</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Properties">Properties</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Property-Managers">Property-Managers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Tenants">Tenants</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Maintanence">Maintanence</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</main>
```